# DataTables and dinamically drawn table

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I'm trying to insert DataTable plugin to my project: I'm using a ajax call to read values from api and then display them onto a table in my home page. Datatable plugin isn't weoking and, from time to time, I keep receveing error 18: column count is correct but I don't know where to correct this error.

```
function persona_table(persona) {
let table = `

    <!-- Creo la tabella -->
    
    <table id="principale" style="width:100%" class="table">
        <thead>

            <tr>
                <th style:"text-align: center">Giorno</th>
                <th style:"text-align: center">Nome</th>
                <th style:"text-align: center">Peso Corporeo</th>
                <th style:"text-align: center">Azioni<th>
            </tr>
        </thead><tbody>`;

        $.each(persona, function(key, val) {

            table+=`
            
            <tr>
                <td>` + val.giorno + `</td>      
                <td style:"text-align: center">` + val.name + `</td>
                <td>` + val.weight_utente + `Kg</td>


                        <td class='text-right'>
                            <div class='btn-group btn-group-sm'>


                            <button  title="button per leggere uno" class='btn btn-primary me-2 leggi_una_persona_button' data-id='` + val.giorno + `'>
                                <span class='fa fa-eye'></span> <small></small>
                            </button>

                            
                            <button title="button per modificare uno" class='btn btn-info me-2 aggiorna_persona_button' data-id='` + val.giorno + `'>
                                <span class='fa fa-edit'></span> <small></small>
                            </button>


                            <button title="button per eliminare uno" class='btn btn-danger cancella_persona_button' data-id='` + val.giorno + `'>
                                <span class='fa fa-remove'></span> <small></small>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </div>
            </tr>`;
        });
table+=`</tbody></table>

return table;  }
```

Problem seemed related to span class in the last column, but that wasn't the case.
Any Idea on how I can procede?

Comment: "_I keep receveing error 18_" - Please add the formatted text of the error to your question. If you are referring to [this](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/18), then show us an example of the JSON (again, as formatted text) returned by your Ajax call. If this happens "from time to time" then make sure you show us the JSON from one of the times when the error did occur.

Comment: One of the best ways to help us is to provide a [mre] in your question. And one way to provide a MRE is to create a [runnable Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/12567365). (You may even solve your own problem, as you create your MRE.)

Comment: Alternatively, using a [HTML validator](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/18#Resolution) may be all you need to do.